# Simplifing a nested IF statement

Tags: c#, simplification

I have a function that is like the following

```
string Foo(bool A, bool B)
{
    if(A)
    {
        if(B)
        {
            return "W";
        }
        else
        {
            return "X";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(B)
        {
            return "Y";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Z";
        }
    }
}
```

That double nesting just feels wrong to me. Is there a better way to implement this pattern?

---

Thank you everyone for helping, I end up going with the trinary route. It helped turn this:

```
if (female)
{
    if (nutered)
    {
        destRow["TargetSex"] = "FS";
    }
    else
    {
        destRow["TargetSex"] = "F";
    }
}
else
{
    if (nutered)
    {
        destRow["TargetSex"] = "MN";
    }
    else
    {
        destRow["TargetSex"] = "M";
    }
}
```

in to this

```
destRow["TargetSex"] = female ? (nutered ? "FS" : "F")
                              : (nutered ? "MN" : "M");
```

Comment: There's always `if(A && B) { } else if (B) { } else { }`

Comment: @DavidStarkey There are 4 possible result states, you only return 3.

Comment: Then `if(A && B) { } else if (!A && B) { } else if (B) { } else { }`

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Which of course should read: `if(A && B) { } else if (A) { } else if (B) { } else { }`.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens Of course :)  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (A)
{
    return B ? "W" : "X";
}
return B ? "Y" : "Z";
```

Or even more terse:

```
return A ? (B ? "W" : "X")  
         : (B ? "Y" : "Z");
```

If your going for exclusively unnested conditions:

```
if (A && B) return "W";
if (A && !B) return "X";
return B ? "Y" : "Z";
```

Comment: Can even do `return A ? (B ? "W" : "X") : (B ? "Y": "Z")`.

Comment: @Yorye That loses a bit of readability for me (personally), and might be overdoing it.

Comment: The "even more terse" solution is the one I like most.

Comment: When using the `even more terse` version, I like to put the colon from the end of the first line right under the question mark after the 'A'. To my eye that scans best of the various placement options.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens see my updated question, I included the real version and how I did it, I did exactly what you suggested already :)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens +1 I really like that syntax.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Logically, no.  You have 4 distinct conditions for two variables.

You can make the code more *concise*, though:

```
string Foo(bool A, bool B)
{
    return A ? 
      B ? "W" : "X"
        :
      B ? "Y" : "Z";

}
```

Or if you're feeling particularly evil, put it on one line with no parens!:

```
return A?B?"W":"X":B?"Y":"Z";
```

Comment: I was looking for better conciseness, I knew there is no logic simplification.

Comment: Those two are tied for the ugliest options I can think of! Do you wear striped ties with your plaid jackets also? +1 for the courage to post those two.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens to be fair, he was the first one to post a trianary solution, steaks posted his in later as a edit.

Answer (score 0):

You four possible states.  A shorter (though not necessarily easier-to-maintain) representation would be

```
if (A && B) {
    return "W";
} else if (A && !B) {
    return "X";
} else if (!A && B) {
    return "Y";
else return "Z";
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have to throw this in for fun:

```
    string Foo(bool A, bool B)
    {
        var labels = new[]{"W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
        return labels[(A ? 0 : 2) + (B ? 0 : 1)];
    }
```

Comment: Clever, When I was originally trying to think of better ways to do it I was actually thought about a similar idea but using a switch statement instead of an array :).